# Possible to hide mesh/texture at a perpendicular viewing angle?

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing, transparency

Is it possible to create a mesh that becomes invisible at certain viewing angles? Id like the mesh or texture to become invisible as it approaches a perpendicular viewing angle.

Current mesh.
[image]

How it looks from certain angle.
[image]

Comment: I think the solution will depend on your rendering engine: Blender's internal or Cycles?

Comment: Any engine will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cycles.

[image]

The idea is to compare view vector (from the "camera data" input node) to the normal of the faces (from "texture coordinate" input node).

If you calculate the dot product it will be low when these two previous vectors are nearly orthogonal.

So, just compare the resulting value to some threshold.

[image]

1- Each input is converted to world

2- The threshold ("greater than" or "lower than" depending on the way you want to use it after)

3- Combined with your texture transparency

[image]

Note: viewing the image in your question, you may also have an alpha values issue (it's not certain but possible)

Comparison node replaced by a colorramp. To be tuned: type of the ramp (cardinal), values of the control points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll check that method out later. Just spent some time finding something that works in internal. I'll post it incase anybody is interested.

Comment: FYI, did not tried it but with Internal you have the same nodes as input (camera data and texture coordinates) and you have an alpha input in extended material node. So that can be the same.

Comment: Had a look at the method you posted. Any idea on how to give it a smooth transition? If not do you know how to set up the method I posted in cycles?

Comment: In fact both answers are using the same principle (direction/normal comparison). To use your technics, simply replace the "greater" or "lesser" than node by a color ramp and place the black control point of the ramp somewhere in the middle of it

Comment: Could you post a node setup? struggling to get it working.

Comment: @Rare, added at the end of the answer

Comment: Thats perfect you have been a great help.

Comment: Hmmm there might actually be a problem with the cycles set up. It doesn't seem to handle multiple objects very well. When I use the clump of leaves as a particle effect the fade effect seems to be missing. thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Method that works in Blender Internal
[image]

Comment: Hi, please edit your answer to include information as to how this works and what it is doing.